# Paypal merchant-sdk-ruby authorization issue on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, paypal

I am using 2 PayPal sdk for payment in my rails application

1. paypal-sdk-merchant for payout and
2. paypal-sdk-rest for collecting payments.

   Both these sdks use same configuration file.

   Paypal-sdk-rest is working fine, but when I initialize a payout call via paypal-sdk-merchant, it give me an error.

```
[#PayPal::SDK::Merchant::DataTypes::ErrorType:0x007fc0f80c7c70 @ShortMessage="Authentication/Authorization Failed", @LongMessage="You do not have permissions to make this API call", @ErrorCode="10002", @SeverityCode="Error"]
```

While I tested the same code on my development machine and it worked like a charm.

It appears that Heroku is blocking our call to Paypal Merchant SDK.

Since the code is working fine in our development environment, this can be a configuration issue.
I also checked that the Ruby and Paypal SDK version are same in both environments.

```
require 'paypal-sdk-merchant'
vets_list = []
vets_list << {
  :ReceiverEmail => 'someone@example.com',
  :Amount => {
  :currencyID => "USD",
  :value => 1.6
  }
}
@api = PayPal::SDK::Merchant::API.new
@mass_pay = @api.build_mass_pay({
  :ReceiverType => "EmailAddress",
  :MassPayItem => vets_list
})
@mass_pay_response = @api.mass_pay(@mass_pay)
```

Can some one figure out what wrong Am I doing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PayPal REST sdk has [payouts support](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK/commit/634b9ba66ac31229681ad97e0e6298a2e0799136) now, so perhaps using that would be an option for you.

Comment: Exactly @Avi. I used PayPal's Rest SDK for this purpose. Actually when I needed to payout, PayPal Rest SDK do not support Mass Pay option. Thanks Anyways.